# Backup MBP to a network attached Disk Drive

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup

Im kind of stuck with this... im following [this link](http://code.stephenmorley.org/articles/time-machine-on-a-network-drive/)?

I get these errors that are in the image.
aka they timed out for some reason.

im upto 5b, stackexchange wont let me put a image...

image link... [here](http://www.grubber.co.nz/stackexchange/Screen%20Shot%202012-12-03%20at%201.05.10%20PM.png)

```
Last login: Sun Dec  2 18:48:23 on ttys000
    Ryans-mbp:~ user$ rsync -aE Ryans_mbp_0023df977bf4.sparsebundle /Volumes/volume1/.
    copyfile(.._Ryans_mbp_0023df977bf4.sparsebundle.EsmCAQ,./Ryans_mbp_0023df977bf4.sparsebundle, COPYFILE_UNPACK) failed:60
    rsync: rename "/Volumes/volume1/./.._Ryans_mbp_0023df977bf4.sparsebundle.EsmCAQ" -> "._Ryans_mbp_0023df977bf4.sparsebundle": Operation timed out (60)
    rsync: mkstemp "/Volumes/volume1/./Ryans_mbp_0023df977bf4.sparsebundle/.Info.bckup.k3eemI" failed: Operation timed out (60)
    rsync: mkstemp "/Volumes/volume1/./Ryans_mbp_0023df977bf4.sparsebundle/.Info.plist.HUQ6D4" failed: Operation timed out (60)
    rsync: mkstemp "/Volumes/volume1/./Ryans_mbp_0023df977bf4.sparsebundle/.token.pQX3lg" failed: Operation timed out (60)
    copyfile(/dev/null, Ryans_mbp_0023df977bf4.sparsebundle/bands, COPYFILE_METADATA) failed:60
    rsync: mkstemp "/Volumes/volume1/./Ryans_mbp_0023df977bf4.sparsebundle/bands/.0.CypYq7" failed: Operation timed out (60)
    rsync: mkstemp "/Volumes/volume1/./Ryans_mbp_0023df977bf4.sparsebundle/bands/.19.ctBo7k" failed: Operation timed out (60)
    rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
    Ryans-mbp:~ user$
```

Comment: Did you execute all the steps in the linked article up to step 6. Have there been any error messages or such?

Comment: @patrix yes I followed up to selecting the disk, because it wouldn't show my network disk. It did have one error, it failed to copy some files over to my network drive as it says 'the operation timed out'

Comment: In which of the steps 1-5 were you required to copy the files which failed?

Comment: 5b is the one i got stuck at

Comment: Can you edit the question accordingly and include a screenshot (or copy/paste from Terminal) of the command you are trying to run and the result?

Comment: @patrix its going to take a little while, all it does is say that some files fail because it times out

Comment: Has there been a follow up on this? I am experiencing the same problem.